# How to make agents wait for capacity to open up before moving?

Tags: anylogic

I have each work cell set up as a Service with capacities set to 1 and delay times are based off of time studies from the floor. Currently, the agents wait for the duration of the delay time, then move to the next Queue, regardless of that next cell having capacity or not.

How can I make them wait for capacity to open up before moving?

Answer (score 0):

In cases like these, you need to split up your Service blocks into their component blocks and sequence them accordingly. Instead of your standard:

```
Seize_1 > Delay_1 > Release_1 > Seize_2 > Delay_2 > Release_2 > etc...
```

you'd have:

```
Seize_1 > Delay_1 > Seize_2 > Release_1 > Delay_2 > Seize_3 > Release_2 > etc...
```

In doing so, your agent will remain in the Seize's queue until the next resource frees itself, and only then releases the previous resource, freeing up space for the next agent.